# How to resolve error invalid_scope for uberats api token access

Tags: oauth-2.0, scope, postman, access-token, uber-api

I'm trying to get token (using Oauth 2.0 protocol) from ubereats API (https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token) but it returns me :

```
{
"error" ; "invalid_scope"
}
```

Here a screenshoot of my postman :
[image]

Here the documentation about that : https://developer.uber.com/docs/eats/api/v2/get-eats-order-orderid

Comment: Did you fix the issue? If you have done please explain how you fix that. Thank you

Comment: @Sajidanwar Hi, I had to contact the uber service because I wasn't in their whitelist. That's why it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your registered client (with the given client_id) can't request the `eats.store` scope. When you're registering an OAuth client you should be able to define what scopes will your client ask for. The Authorization Server should show this information somewhere - which scopes can your client request. I don't know if Uber has a developer portal where you can view your clients, but if they have then you should be able to see the scopes allowed for your client there.

If you can't find that information I think you should reach out to Uber and verify with them if your client can request the given scope.